# Does this circuit look like a battery charger or a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, lithium-ion, wall-wart

In my project, in order to charge a Li-ion battery pack (2200 mAh, 13.8 V), I am proposed a wall adapter integrating the following circuit:

[image]

I do not have the part numbers of U1 and U3.

The process of charging a lithium-ion battery should be at fixed current with voltage slowly rising, and when the rated voltage is reached, the current slowly decreases. So, to me, this circuit is a simple power supply, am I right? I am not used to this kind of schematic which is why I need to make sure.

If it indeed is a simple power supply, can I still use it to charge the battery? Could it degrade the battery performance with time?

Comment: Details of U3 are necessary to understand what this circuit does.

Comment: Strange that current shunt measurement is connected to Vsense. Should be Isense?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that U3 is a GRE0141 or SE1052 constant voltage/constant current chip. At least the pins match...

Answer (score 1):

What this circuit does is fully defined by U1's behaviour. If you don't know U1, you can't say whether it's a constant current, or a  constant voltage supply, or something more complex. U1 seems to be essentially controlled by U3's output, so without knowing U3 and U1, you basically don't know most of your circuit.

I'll say that you're *probably* wrong, as this looks a bit too complex for just a plain power supply, and the circuit would have all the *means* for U1 and U3 together to integrate current to have a notion of the charging status of a battery, but there's really no way to know without knowing U1 and U3.